# Where is the value of an input stored after changing it in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Reactjs with bootstrap, it has an input field of text which use bootstrap-datepicker to choose date.

After I choose a date, the value of the input field is not stored, so the state of reactjs component cannot be changed. I didn't see a change in the dom's value, text or anything, so where is this value changed and why reactjs cannot detect the change?

I am using an input and javascript to load the picker:

```
$('.date-input').datepicker();
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about choosing the datepicker as a source of the value? is this possible? maybe about the data-attribute?

Comment: Can you update your code here?

Comment: How are you using bootstrap exactly? Is this `react-bootstrap` or are you calling `$('input').datepicker()` on something?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used bootstrap for my development, but generally the content of the input box is stored in two ways when it comes to react.

1. defaultValue
2. value.

If you provide a defaultValue and dont assign a onChange function to it then the input box will be a readOnly textbox.

To change the content of the input box provide a onChange event where you set the content state of the input box. In this way you can change the value inside the input box.

So from the looks of it in your case, set the state of the input box component from your datepicker to change the value of the input box component.